# How to understand this C++ code from Boost library?

Tags: c++

I came across the following code in the Boost library `default_attribute_names.hpp`. I am trying to understand the below code.

What I understand is, a function name severity() is declared which returns an object of class attribute_name. I tried to locate an implementation of this function within the library but failed. Is this some thing else than what I think. And also, what is this BOOST_LOG_API. I could not find any tutorial with such language syntax. How can I understand this code?

```
namespace default_attribute_names {

BOOST_LOG_API attribute_name severity();
BOOST_LOG_API attribute_name channel();
BOOST_LOG_API attribute_name message();
BOOST_LOG_API attribute_name line_id();
BOOST_LOG_API attribute_name timestamp();
BOOST_LOG_API attribute_name process_id();
BOOST_LOG_API attribute_name thread_id();

}
```

Comment: `BOOST_LOG_API` is a macro name defined somewhere above (in an, possibly indirectly, included header perhaps). `severity()`'s definition can be somewhere else in a source file so, in your system, it only exists in binary form. Have you searched through the whole Boost sources? They are available.

Comment: You've posted part of a [header file](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/).  This particular part shows some [function prototypes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-function-prototype/).  `attribute` is the return type of these functions.  The definition of type `attribute` is in another, different header: "attribute_name.hpp".  The definition for `BOOST_LOG_API` is in yet a third different header: "core.hpp".

Comment: thanks, when I tried go to definition in my VC project, it ends up in the declaration  itself and does not show eny definition.

Answer (score 1):

A header file is part of code that meant to be used from several Operating systems, with different compilers, and several of project types.

In windows, if you compile to a DLL, you should declare export symbols, but if you compile to a static library you shouldn't.

Another issue is when you include the header to use a DLL from other project you should import symbols from DLL, while when you use the header inside the project you should export the symbols.

Therefore, usually you can find a similar macro in each cross platform class or function.

it usually may declared like this:

```
//from inside a DLL (on windows) which declare the symbols:
#define BOOST_LOG_API __declspec(dllexport)

//from code which use symbols which declared in other DLL:
#define BOOST_LOG_API __declspec(dllimport) 

//in static lib, or none windows code it can be empty:
#define BOOST_LOG_API 

//sometimes you want to prevent name mangling by adding extern "C" to API macro. (can be used only for functions not for classes)
//so it may be: (you can add it to any of the macros)
#define BOOST_LOG_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

Usually you use other macro in manner to generate the correct macro. Like this:

```
#ifndef BOOST_LOG_API 
# ifdef WIN32
#  if defined(BOOST_LOG_EXPORT)
#   define BOOST_LOG_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#  elif defined(BOOST_LOG_IMPORT)
#   define BOOST_LOG_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#  else 
#   define BOOST_LOG_API
#  endif
# else
#  define BOOST_LOG_API
# endif
#endif
```